# Code in tap() and subscribe() not being executed by test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a private method that basically fetches data from a service and updates a cache variable if that value changed. Something like this:

```
private refreshMyData() {

   this.myDataService.getMyData$().pipe(

      tap(()=> console.log('reached here !!')),
      skipWhile(myData => isEqual(mydata, this.myDataCache))

   ).subscribe(myData => {
       this.myDataCache = myData;
       console.log('Cache update Done!')
   }); 

}
```

This works fine, but Im trying to write a test - where cache should be updated.

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
   let component: MyComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

   beforeEach(async () => {
      await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports:[HttpClientTestingModule],
         declarations: [ MyComponent],
         providers: [MyDataService, MyService2, MyService3, ...]
         })
         .compileComponents();

   beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });


it('should update cache Data', fakeAsync(() => {

   component['myDataCache'] = new cacheData(); //init cache with empty instance
   let myDataMock = { ... } //mocked object i want to test the observable with

   let myDataSvc = TestBed.inject(MyDataService);
   let getMyDataSpy = spyOn(myDataSvc,'getMyData$').and.returnValue(of(myDataMock));

   component['refreshMyData']();

   tick();

   expect(component['myDataCache']).toEqual(myDataMock);

 })); });
```

This fails.
Fist, none of my console.logs gets executed.
Also, cache does not get updated and test fails.

Any suggestions on how to approach this test?

Comment: I am not sure why the log in the `tap` is not logged but I think I see one problem with your test. You're using `.toBe` for  a reference type (object, array) but I think you should use `.toEqual`. `.toBe` is === and `.toEqual` can be used for object and reference types for not strict equality.

Comment: First of all the tick() is not usefull since the subscribe will be resolved at the call because the the of(myDataMock) operator. Can you show the definition of the TestBed ?

Comment: @AliF50 yeah, i get that. If I get the test to fail because of the ToBe assertion than that would be massive progress. Im focusing on why the code (that includes the console logs) is not running.

Comment: @JFPicard Ive updated the code, hope it makes sense. Im not using my real components name, but the logic is all there.

Comment: I don't see any problem in that code. Are you sure that:  let getMyDataSpy = spyOn(myDataSvc,'getMyData$').and.returnValue(of(myDataMock)); is using the real name of the function ? Have you tried without $ ?